# change color of button when highlighted in iphone

Tags: iphone

how to change the color of the button when i just touch it...i mean to say when the button is higlighted. i want to change the default Blue color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: [setBackgroundImage:forState](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:)

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:genericImage forStates:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonBackgroundPressed  
                   forStates:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: do i need an image or can i set an hex value to change the color?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it, the easier way, is within Interface Builder.

- Select the button that you want to adjust the state colors for
- Hit CMD+1, selects the first tab called "Button Attributes"
- You can set the different attributes for the different states by clicking on the Drop Down List which currently says "Default State Configuration"